# material-ui installation npm dependencies

Tags: reactjs, npm, material-ui

I am new to React and NPM.
I created a new directory, did `npm init`, `npm install` and I installed React.

This is now my `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "reactapp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^15.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.7.6",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.4",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.6.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.5.0",
    "webpack": "^1.12.15"
  }
}
```

The problem is while installing `material-ui` I got this screen and I can't really understand how I can fix it.

[image: screen print]

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

You have installed React v15.

`material-ui` expects older version of React.

But you shouldn't worry, because material-ui works nicely with React v15.

So just ignore this warnings. They will dissapear after next update of `material-ui` library by its mainteiners.

Or you can install `v0.14` of react

Comment: If you are in a hurry, you could also accept alpha, beta or release versions of material-ui, by requiring `"material-ui": "~0.15.0-0"` in your package.json. material-ui is currently up to version 0.15.0-beta.1 and works smoothly with React v15.

Comment: I have run into unexplainable bugs with `alpha`. I would strongly discourage using it.

Comment: or just install the newly published beta of `material-ui` 0.15: https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/releases/tag/v0.15.0-beta.1

==> `npm i --save material-ui@0.15.0-beta.1`